# Random Drawing coordinates

Tags: java, random, jframe, draw

Hey I need to write a code that would be randomly generating coordinates for squares, circles and  so on. I tried it that way (I skipped Main class):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Oval extends JPanel {

        Random random1 = new Random(100);
        Random random2 = new Random(100);
        Random random3 = new Random(100);
        Random random4 = new Random(100);

        int x1 = random1.nextInt();
        int x2 = random2.nextInt();
        int x3 = random3.nextInt();
        int x4 = random4.nextInt();

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);      

            //oval
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(30, 40, 20, 20);

            //rectangle
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(x1, x2, x3, x4);

            //triangle
            int xpoints[] = {165, 145, 205, 145, 145};
            int ypoints[] = {65, 125, 115, 145, 105};
            int npoints = 3;
            g.setColor(Color.pink);
            g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);

            //trapezoid
            int trxpoints[] = {265, 285, 305, 245, 245};
            int trypoints[] = {165, 165, 215, 225, 205};
            int trnpoints = 4;
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillPolygon(trxpoints, trypoints, trnpoints);  
        }
 }
```

I filled rectangle' coordinates with random numbers, but in the end it fills my whole JFrame with a color reserved for a rectangle. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*Why does this happens?* This happens because you are creating 4 instances of `Random` with the **same seed**.  You are passing `100` (same seed) as argument when you initialize the `Random` objects. This seed is useful to repeat random calls. In your case, each `Random` object will return the same *random* sequence when a method is called. If you want to try this yourself, create two `Random` instances with the same seed and try calling and printing the result f some methods.

*How to solve this?* Just create one, and call `nextInt()` for each variable `x1`, `x2`. Also, I would recommend you to do this (initialization) in the constructor:

```
Random random1;
int x1;
int x2;
int x3;
int x4;

public Test()
{
    random1 = new Random(100); // Give a seed if you want to run 
                               // the program with same random sequence each time
                               // If you want different sequences each time
                               // you run the program use 'new Random()'
    x1 = random1.nextInt();
    x2 = random1.nextInt();
    x3 = random1.nextInt();
    x4 = random1.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
    Random random1 = new Random(100);
    Random random2 = new Random(100);
    Random random3 = new Random(100);
    Random random4 = new Random(100);
```

This gives you identical sequences for every `random*` variable.

Secondly:

`nextInt` method:

> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability

It gives you values that are really big (much bigger than your frame)

I suggest doing as follows:

```
random.nextInt(this.getWidth()), random.nextInt(this.getHeight())
```